# 1940 US Census - indexed data?

Tags: usa, us-census, census, demographics

I read a [fascinating article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/03/23/will-this-years-census-be-the-last) about the census in the US, and especially the 1940 census, which is [available online](https://1940census.archives.gov/search) (since the 72 year period has elapsed).

I was able to search based on address (and cross streets), but was wondering if anything else has been indexed. For example, people's names.

There is some info about funded projects in 2012 to digitize the data ([one](https://www.research.gov/research-portal/appmanager/base/desktop?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=researchAreas_11&_urlType=action&wlpresearchAreas_11_id=%2FresearchGov%2FAwardHighlight%2FPublicAffairs%2F2013%2F24170_RetrievingdigitizeddatafromtheUSCensus.html&wlpresearchAreas_11_action=selectAwardDetail) : [two](https://www.research.gov/research-portal/appmanager/base/desktop;jsessionid=73PLpQjN4jxNQqTkGHzhF7x8jH5hv1p2qjVJj3y4N9Hn3xztp2qT!1329000707!-830358432?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=awards_1&_urlType=action&wlpawards_1_action=viewAwardDetailEvent_rsr&wlpawards_1_fedAwrdId=1053575) : [three](https://www.archives.gov/research/genealogy/census/online-resources)), but I haven't found any portal or available dataset.

[image]

*Art credit from the New Yorker article linked above. Artist: [Tim Peacock](https://timpeacock.com/)*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just docu images.

The census website wont allow hotlinks but if you look there at historical data it will tell you more.

https://1940census.archives.gov/index.asp